# Alarm taking at least 1 min on android 5.1

Tags: android

I have a functionality that works for long time and hits the backend in the interval of every 10 seconds.

Problem:
The alarm is not working for this small interval i.e. 10 seconds but the same gets hit after 1 min even after setting an alarm with the repeating intervals of 10 seconds.

This has been working fine until I upgraded to `android 5.1 on my Moto g`. Also I have tested the same piece of code on my `android 4.2.2 samsung galaxy s4`.

**Is this a bug in android 5.1 that should be logged ?**

Sample code:

**Activity**

```
package com.example.alarm_game;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private AlarmManager obdAlarmManager;
    private PendingIntent obdPendingIntent;
    private Intent obdIntent;

    private Button alarmOn,alarmOff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmOn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_on);
        alarmOff=(Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_off);

        alarmOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                initiliseTimer(MainActivity.this,10000);
            }
        });

        alarmOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopAlarm();
            }
        });

    }

    public void initiliseTimer(Context context, long time) {

        obdAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        obdIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        obdIntent.setData(Uri.parse("timer:"+System.currentTimeMillis()));
        obdPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123454,
                obdIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        obdAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, time,
                obdPendingIntent);
    }

    public void stopAlarm()
    {
        if (obdAlarmManager != null) {

            if(obdPendingIntent!=null)
             obdPendingIntent.cancel();

            obdAlarmManager.cancel(obdPendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Receiver**:

```
package com.example.alarm_game;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm hit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug in android 5.1 that should be logged ?

No, insofar as [1) it was already logged and 2) it is working as intended](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244). The minimum repeat interval on Android 5.1+ is 1 minute.

See also [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/03/23/alarmmanager-regression-android-5p1.html).

Comment: But what should be done as to handle the sleep/standby mode that is the advantage of using alarm-manager and hence I used it from the API.

Comment: @prateek: Well, first, realize that it's not going to work on Android 6.0+ due to Doze mode, unless this device is always plugged in or always moving. Ignoring that, you are welcome to use `setExact()` and do your own repeating, as is [described in the issue comments](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244#c11).